# How to print a value returned by a class method

Tags: c++, class, methods, cout

I am having troubles printing a value returned by a class method. In the DataClass instance, cout *will* print the dataMember (an int) using a statement of the form:

```
cout << dataClassInstance.getDataMember();
```

However the ListEntry, which contains a DataClass as a member, is unable to print that same value using its own function. The Form is:

```
cout << listEntryInstance.getDataClass();
```

ListEntry uses its own get function which calls the DataClass's get function to return the same int value but it gives an error instead:

> [Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are
>   'std::basic_ostream' and 'DataClass')

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated. I can't seem to find any solutions from what I've looked at so far.

```
class DataClass 
{
    private:
    dataType dataMember;

    public:
    //default   
    DataClass() 
    {
        dataMember;  
    }

    //parameterized
    DataClass(dataType inputData)
    {
        dataMember = inputData;
    }

    //copy
    DataClass(const DataClass &inputData)
    {
        dataMember = inputData.dataMember;
    }

    //destructor
    ~DataClass() 
    {

    }

    //set
    void setData(dataType inputData)
    {
        dataMember = inputData;
    }

    //get
    dataType getDataMember()
    {
        return dataMember;
    }

};

class ListEntry
{
    private:
    DataClass data;
    ListEntry* nextEntryPtr;
    ListEntry* prevEntryPtr;

    public:
    //default
    ListEntry() : data()
    {

        nextEntryPtr = NULL;
        prevEntryPtr = NULL;
    }

    //parameterized
    ListEntry(const DataClass& inputData) : data(inputData) 
    {
        nextEntryPtr = NULL;
        prevEntryPtr = NULL;    
    }

    //copy
    ListEntry(const ListEntry& entryToCopy) : data(entryToCopy.data)
    {
        nextEntryPtr = NULL;
        prevEntryPtr = NULL;
    }

    //destructor
    ~ListEntry() 
    {

    }   

    //set
    void setDataClass(DataClass dataInput)
    {
        data.setData(dataInput.getDataMember());
    }

    void setNextEntry(ListEntry* entryPtr)
    {
        nextEntryPtr = entryPtr;
    }

    void setPrevEntry(ListEntry* entryPtr)
    {
        prevEntryPtr = entryPtr;
    }

    //get
    DataClass getDataClass()
    {
        return data.getDataMember();
    }

    ListEntry* getNextEntry()
    {
        return nextEntryPtr;
    }

    ListEntry* getPrevEntry()
    {
        return prevEntryPtr;
    }

};
```

Sample of the code I'm using to test the functionality of each class. DataClass gives the expected results, ListEntry only gives an error.

```
//STUB TEST FOR DATACLASS 
dataType constructTest = 42;

cout << "Creating DataClass with default constructor." 
     << endl;

DataClass defaultTestData; //default initialize

cout << "Value held in DataClass: " 
     << defaultTestData.getDataMember() 
     << endl << endl;



//STUB TEST FOR LISTENTRY

cout << "Creating list entry with default constructor." << endl;
ListEntry defaultEntry;

cout << "Value held in list entry:" 
     << defaultEntry.getDataClass() 
     << endl << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print a `DataClass`, not a member of it. For this class, you have not specified how to print it (by overloading the `<<` operator). That is what the compiler is complaining about.

What you want is probably

```
cout << listEntryInstance.getDataClass().getDataMember();
```

Comment: That snippit of code does compile, but I am getting garbage numbers for both the default constructors of `DataClass` and `ListEntry`. I was getting the correct output earlier, so I must have changed something. Gonna do some investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Stream insertion operator isn't overloaded for DataClass

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const DataClass &dc) {
    out << dc.dataMember;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: I see...that makes sense. I went ahead and overloaded the << operator for DataClass but the compiler didn't like that. It's saying that dataMember is private in the context of `out << dc.dataMember << std::endl;`. I tried using `dc.getDataMember` since that's a public method, and that also doesn't compile.

Comment: It is a bad practice to have endl in operator<< for two reasons: (1) it forces flush, which can slow down the code; (2) does not give the caller an option to avoid the newline